# How to filter list in RXJava

Tags: rx-java, filtering

I'm trying to filter a `single<list<item>>` that I get from a method

```
return getList(number)
    .filter { it -> it.age }  <--- problem
    .flatMap { addMoreData(it) }
    .map(mapper)

fun getList(number: Int): Single<List<Item>> {
    //do so things   
}
```

But in this case I can't do it because `it` has a `List<Item>` instead of `Item`.
I want it to be in RXJava (don't want to run a method which loops the list and filter it)

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `getList()` returns `Single<List<Item>>`, then I think [`flattenAsObservable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#flattenAsObservable-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) is what you want:

```java
return getList()
    .flattenAsObservable { it -> it } // Turns it into Observable<Item>
    .filter { it -> it.age }
    .flatMap { addMoreData() }
    .map(mapper)
```

You can also use `.flatMapObservable { list -> Observable.fromIterable(list) }`, but it's a little more verbose.